# What is the difference between angular momentum of electron by Bohr and orbital angular momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals

Orbital angular momentum of an electron is $\hbar \sqrt{\ell(\ell+1)}$ where $\ell$ is angular quantum number.

Angular momentum of an electron by Bohr is given by $mvr$ or $\frac{nh}{2\pi}$ (where $v$ is the velocity, $n$ is the orbit in which electron is, $m$ is mass of the electron, and $r$ is the radius of the $n$'th orbit).

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_angular_momentum_of_free_electrons

Answer (score 0):

In quantum mechanics, The eigenvalues of the total angular momentum operator $(L^2$) and angular momentum operator ($L_z$) look like
$$L^2|lm\rangle =l(l+1)\hbar^2|lm\rangle $$
$$L_z|lm\rangle =m\hbar |lm\rangle $$

---

The second equation can be recognized as Bohr's condition,  that the angular momentum is an integer multiple of ħ was later reinterpreted by de Broglie as a standing wave condition: the electron is described by a wave and a whole number of wavelengths must fit along the circumference of the electron's orbit:
$$n\lambda=2\pi r$$
$$\Rightarrow l=n\hbar$$

Comment: Though correct this answer isn't accessible to most introductory students on this material.